# Get attribute from join model (belongs_to) rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have 2 related models.

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :subdomain
  belongs_to  :theme
end

class Theme < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :screenshot_attributes
  has_many  :stores
end
```

Everything works fine the problem is when I try to access the theme's name in the following way.

```
<% @stores.each do |store| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to store.subdomain, store %></td>
    <td><%= store.name %></td>
    <td><%= store.theme.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Go to Store', root_url(subdomain: store.subdomain) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', [:edit, store] %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', store, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

This is the line that gets the error.

```
    <td><%= store.theme.name %></td>
```

And this is the message:

```
    undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

What is the correct way to access the theme's name value?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because store.theme is nil. A usefull function is inspect. If you do:

```
<%= store.inspect %>
```

You will see theme_id is nil.

Comment: Theme_id is not nil. When I do <%= store.theme.inspect %> I get: #<Theme id: 6, name: "ferus", created_at: "2012-12-06 20:13:18", updated_at: "2012-12-06 23:09:39", description: "...">

Comment: Ok, now I see! I had **only 1** of the records without theme_id. Thank you!

Comment: Here is a useful function for when values in your view may be nil: http://everydayrails.com/2011/04/28/rails-try-method.html